# Why routing Don't Work in Angular 4?

Tags: angular

I have this code:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { AuthRegComponent } from './Components/Auth_Reg/Auth_Reg.component';

import { FirstSetupComponent } from './Components/First_Setup/First_Setup.component';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'setup', component: FirstSetupComponent },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'home',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'home',
    component: AuthRegComponent
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, { enableTracing: true })
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ],
  providers: [

  ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Path **""** and **home** wor. If I try /setup, I see `AuthReg` component. But the `FirstSetupComponent` component should be displayed. If the `FirstSetupComponent` component is substituted in number. I will still see `AuthRegComponent` again.

My app.module code:

```
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';

import { AuthRegComponent } from './Components/Auth_Reg/Auth_Reg.component';

import { FirstSetupComponent } from './Components/First_Setup/First_Setup.component';
import { TestService } from './Services/service.test'; 

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AuthRegComponent,
    FirstSetupComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule, HttpClientModule, HttpModule, AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [
    TestService],
  bootstrap: [AuthRegComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the following

1. If you have put the router outlet in the correct place such as app.component.html
2. You should try to access your route like below

   ```
   <a [routerLink]="['/user/dummy']">
      link to user component
   </a>
   ```
3. If you have done the above 2 correctly check the console